# Changes in runtime as the input is incremented

Tags: runtime-analysis

I have a bit of problem in the question below, mainly in the case of incrementing the input size (it doesn't seem solvable to me, like, do we just write $f(n)/f(n+1)$ or...), and also the logarithm ones because I'm not really comfortable with those.

I'd appreciate it a lot if you could take the time to explain them to me.Thank you.

[image: picture of the questions]

Comment: Yes, the first one is a badly formulated question, if they haven't defined how do they want you quantify "How much slower". Maybe you can quantify it as a factor $\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$, like you said, or the difference $f(n+1)-f(n)$, or the proportion of the difference to the value $\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{f(n)}$.

Comment: Thank you, would you mind helping me with the other question as well so I accept it as an answer? Thanks nonetheless.